# bash not able to execute command in a variable

Tags: bash

```
cdm="home/nmsadm/tngVersion/iconTestNetworkGenerator.sh -input /home/nmsadm/ipr/ipr_files/IP_1.xml -templateDir /home/nmsadm/Try_K/1 -nocs -erbsstart 1 -subnetwork 25 -iprstart 11"

#above statment is in a single line

$cdm
```

I stored one command in a variable called `cdm`, now I want to run this command so I used `$cdm`. But I'm getting an error

> `home/nmsadm/tngVersion/iconTestNetworkGenerator.sh: No such file or directory`

I'm pretty sure that there is file in that specified directory.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Would you at least take a bit of time to format your question and spell words in full (other people already improved your question, so please remember how it should look for next time)? When you don't even care to write properly, why do you expect people to care to solve your problem?

Comment: Also, use arrays, instead of single string containing command+parameters...

Comment: @anishsane : could you plz tell me how to use the arrays, with example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is apparently trying to execute the command. The error quotes the command name from the variable. But the command is wrong. Did you by any chance forget initial `/`?

Comment: Yes, u r correct , thankx :)                   cdm="/home/nmsadm/tngVersion/iconTestNetworkGenerator.sh -input /home/nmsadm/ipr/ipr_files/IP_1.xml -templateDir /home/nmsadm/Try_K/1 -nocs -erbsstart 1 -subnetwork 25 -iprstart 11"

Answer (score 2):

Since you specified the name of a command along with a directory the command is supposed to be in, there is no `PATH` lookup performed. Apparently you are not in a directory where the pathname

```
  home/nmsadm/tngVersion/iconTestNetworkGenerator.sh
```

refers to an existing file. Fix this either by using an absolute path, probably

```
  /home/nmsadm/tngVersion/iconTestNetworkGenerator.sh
```

or by cd'ing to the proper directory first, probably

```
  cd /
  $cmd
```